# How to add a table in django app models from PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have created a django project named `Book Store`. In my project I have one app named `books`.

I am using PostgreSQL DBMS. I have a database called `books`. In that database, I have a table named `novel`. How do I add this table in the `models.py` file inside `books` app?

I want to register this table under admin site. After successfully adding this table in the `models.py` file, I believe, I shall be able to register the table in the admin site by writing the following codes in the `admin.py` file under `books` app.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . models import novel

admin.site.register(novel)
```

I also want to know that if my approach is correct or is there any better way available? As I am new to django, I don't know much about it.

I have read `django-book` but didn't find out my answer. There is an article about `SQLite` database though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The convention here is that you should create your models first then you can create database tables to bind with by migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

there is another way which you can make django automatically create models for you based on the already implemented database tables:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: more about Django models: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/

Comment: Second one works but imports all the table in the app. First one doesn't work. I have create model as `class novel(models.Model):` and then run the first two command in shell.